Github matrix Strategy step output aggregation to get the final status of the execution
I have a github actions workflow running with matrix stragegy
In my workflow as part of the matrix , i am running , terraform plan and static scan
The matrix executes on different directories ( workdir, network, app)
At the end of the workflow i want to capture the status of each individual executions that happend as part of the matrix workflow and aggregate and get the final status as success (if all execution were successfull)  or failure
I couldnt get it working, the status of 1 run is not maintained when the next run executes in the matrix
IS there any way to do it?

See https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/17245 and https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26639.

Thank you for the direction , i will refer to the above discussions
